# How to Clear web config file This error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

iam getting bthis error from in my local database web config.
Cannot open database "bedoonzaytdb" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'ARABSWELL\IUSR_ARABSWELL'.can anyone know find this error.thank in advance

Comment: Check your connection string...and/or make sure the database is set up for Windows authentication and lets the web server user access it.

Comment: @cHao-i dont know how to given windows authenticationcan anyone know let me know.thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means, you need to give permission to the database which you mentioned in your question.

Follow the instructions :

=> Open Sql Server

=> Go to object Explorer

=> Explore Security tab

=> Do right click on Login

=> Click on new login

=> Write the name as 'ARABSWELL\IUSR_ARABSWELL' in login name

=> And then click on USERMAPPING from left tab

=> Make select your database name from the list provided in right side.

=> After that provide role to your database as you want. Basically you should select Public,datareader and datawriter.

=> Finally click ok and restart the sql server.

Now run your application. You will find your way.

Note : The above instructions are verified in SQL SERVER 2008. The concept is same for all the server, but the procedure may vary depends on the IDE.

Comment: @gkrishy-- i did u said instruction only to my windows authenication but i cant login in my IIS server .when im login that time.but in local when im executing its loging..why the the problem in IIS server  can anyone know let me know .Thank in Advance

Comment: What type of IIS you are using ?

Comment: @gkrishy-its normal Windows SP3 default IIS

Comment: @gkrishy-how can i remove this windows authentication 'ARABSWELL\IUSR_ARABSWELL' else i want to update this authentication options is there any options to update

Comment: You can edit the same login as many times as you want. Simply explore Login tab, you will find your login. Then do right click and go to properties and change your role as you want.

Comment: Do deploy your application again in your IIS by removing old. Use Virtual path to deploy it.

Comment: @gkrishy-can u know why its not login in IIS sever but its loging in Local database(Mean when im executing my application) ..can u find the problem..but I got Index page but IIS server login time its not login can u know means let me know ..thank in advance

Comment: @gkrishy-can u explain proper deployement in SP3 default IIS instructions in our Applications.thank in advance

Comment: What's index page represents in your application ?. You can set default page in iis itslef.

Comment: Are you using IIS 7 ?. What's your OS ?

Comment: @gkrishy-im using windows XP only .Thank in advance any other source

Comment: Follow this (link)[http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32210/Deployment-of-a-Website-on-IIS]

Comment: You need to give permission here too. Choose your role at Step 4 from the above link.

Comment: @gkrishy--k i will check now ..after that let me know

Comment: @gkrishy-Application Pool Connection is not coming in my IIS server how can i enable that one can u knoe find me that answser.Thank in advance

Comment: Try by execute till step 5.

Comment: @gkrishy--Application Pool option not in my IIS Server how can i take that options

Comment: Follow only first 5 steps. That is, "Making Virtual Directory". Don't indulge in Virtual Directory Settings